# why javascript removes forward slash from image url, how I can fix it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am writing some HTML code inside JavaScript where I also used inline css to add background-image using background-img property.
But on browser image is not showing and when I checked in console image path is doesn't have forward slash.

> ```
> let cardsObject = 
> [
>     {
>         title:"FMCG-F&B", discription:"marketing and business 
>         planning",imgPath:"./images/firm3.jpg"
>     } 
>
> ]
>
> function cardShow() {
> let featCards =""; 
> cardsObject.forEach(cObj=>{
>     
>     featCards+=
>     `
>     <div class="card mr-2 mt-2"
>     style=
>     "
>     background-image: url("${cObj.imgPath}");
>     background-size: cover;
>     object-fit: contain;
>     "
>     >
>         <div class="innerCard">
>             <h5 class="cardHeading text-center text-uppercase ">
>                 ${cObj.title}
>             </h5>
>         </div>
>         <p class="cardDeatils">
>         ${cObj.discription}
>         </p>
>     </div>
>
>     `
>     
> })
>
> document.getElementById("featuresCards").innerHTML = featCards; }
> ```

in console background image path is showing like this

> background-image: url(". images firm3.jpg");

without forward slashes
can anyone suggest me how I can fix this issue.

Comment: Looks like you are using double quotes within double quotes for the style attribute.  Try changing to single quotes where `url("${cObj.imgPath}")` becomes `url('${cObj.imgPath}')`

Comment: thank you, yeah that's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact you dont need the quotes for setting background url.
can be set as :-

```
background: url(${cObj.imgPath});
```

```js
let cardsObject = 
[
    {
        title:"FMCG-F&B", discription:"marketing and business planning",imgPath:"./images/firm3.jpeg"
    } 

];

(function cardShow() {
    let featCards =""; 
    cardsObject.forEach((cObj) => {
        
        featCards+=
        `
        <div class="card mr-2 mt-2"
        style=
        "
        background: url(${cObj.imgPath});
        background-size: cover;
        object-fit: contain;
        "
        >
            <div class="innerCard">
                <h5 class="cardHeading text-center text-uppercase ">
                    ${cObj.title}
                </h5>
            </div>
            <p class="cardDeatils">
            ${cObj.discription}
            </p>
        </div>

        `
        
    });

    document.getElementById("featuresCards").innerHTML = featCards; 
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="featuresCards"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you, yeah that's the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple fix to an error caused by the double-quotes you are using in your `background-image` style:

```
style=
"
background-image: url("${cObj.imgPath}");
background-size: cover;
object-fit: contain;
"
```

Note the double-quote surrounding the `style` attribute that then contains another double-quote to surround the `url` of the image path.

Instead, switch the `url` quotes to singles (so `url("...")` becomes `url('...')`):

```
style=
"
background-image: url('${cObj.imgPath}');
background-size: cover;
object-fit: contain;
"
```

And this will work exactly as expected.

Comment: thank you dear, that the issue.